# Split string using pattern VBA regex

Tags: regex, vba

Although there is already lots of regex topic, I couldn't find a good solution to split a string like this: 12ABC34DE**102/103/104**FG

Result should be: 12ABC34DE**102**FG | 12ABC34DE**103**FG | 12ABC34DE**104**FG

EDIT: Other example: 12ABC34DE**102/103***AH001/AH002* should be 12ABC34DE**102***AH001* | 12ABC34DE**103***AH001* | 12ABC34DE**102***AH002* | 12ABC34DE**103***AH002*

With this regex: `([0-9]{2,3})*\/([0-9]{2,3})*`, I'm able to get into groups the changing values but I cannot go further.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you may want to first capture the forward slash delimited substring and then use `Split()` to create an array to go over. Something like so:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "12ABC34DE102/103/104FG"
Dim arr() As String, x As Long

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "\d{2,3}(?:/\d{2,3})+"
    If .Test(str) Then
        arr = Split(.Execute(str)(0), "/")
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            arr(x) = .Replace(str, arr(x))
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Running this will end up with:

[image]

Comment: Great, I like that!

Comment: Hello, thank you but I forgot one condition and your solution is not working in this case. I edited the question, there could be several slashes with different pattern (the pattern is not the issue but the additional slash is because it cannot be use in the split then)

Comment: @Kokno, that would complicate the matter. The above gave you a good idea of what to look for. Try to adapt the code, do your research. I'm not going to keep writing code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: @JvdV yes your answer already helped me and I adapted it to the new case, thank you